# How a C string pointer within a string is null-terminated?

Tags: c, string, pointers, null-terminated

Let's say I have a C string `ch` with parameter-value pairs:

```
#include <string.h>
char ch[] = "name=John sex=male age=30"; // null-terminated C string
char *p, *v; // pointers to parameter and value

p = strstr(ch, "sex="); // p now points to "sex=male age=30"
sscanf(p, "sex=%s", v); // get the value for sex
printf("sex = %s\n", v); // gives "male", works as expected
printf("length of v is %i\n", strlen(v)); // gives 4
printf("is v null-terminated? %i\n", (*(v+4)=='\0')); // gives 1
```

My understanding is that `p` points to "sex=M age=30" in `ch`, and uses the same null terminator as `ch`. `v` points to "male" in `p`, and **my question is where the null terminator for `v` is stored**? It is a space after "male" in both `p` and `ch`, and here `v` is a pointer, not a buffer.

Comment: I understand now I should do something like `char v[5]` rather than `char *v`. It crashes when I print `ch` after `sscanf`. Without printing, it worked for me thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my question is where the null terminator for v is stored?

There isn't. You are invoking [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `v` is uninitialized. Not only the null terminator but the writing "male" by sscanf() into the location pointed to by `v` is invalid. Because `v` doesn't point to a valid memory location.

`sscanf()` would do the null termination but you must pass a valid pointer (e.g. `char v[5]`). Note that `sscanf()` doesn't modify its first argument at all. So `ch` won't be modified by `sscanf()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand now I was using `sscanf` incorrectly, although it worked for me. But when I print `ch` after `sscanf` as @Mark Tolenen commented, it crashed. How would this happen? As you said `sscanf` won't modify its first argument.

Comment: That's possibly because of the *undefined behaviour*. Writing to uninitialized `v` might end writing somewhere. Does it happen even if you use `char v[5];` as well?

Comment: Once I changed to `char v[5]`, there is no any problem. Thank you.